# Worklight Hybrid app back button issue on IOS9

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ios9

Worklight hybrid apps back buttons are broken on IOS9 because following piece of code is broken.

```
window.history.back();
```

As per following link the solution is to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8254

We are using worklight 6.2.x, which generates IOS code, is there any alternate way to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a configuration change in JQuery Mobile that resolves this issue.

[Problems with window.history using JQuery/Javascript on Cordova app in IOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187431/problems-with-window-history-using-jquery-javascript-on-cordova-app-in-ios9)

Answer (score 0):

The way it works in Worklight Hybrid applications is that Cordova’s ViewController is used to display, to render, the web resources - the app. This ViewController that is provided by Cordova (and cannot be replaced) uses iOS’s UIWebView.

Therefore, until Cordova addresses this in the Cordova codebase by moving from using UIWebView to using WKWebView this defect cannot be fixed in Hybrid apps generated by Worklight - because they use what Cordova supplies them with.

As a possible workaround, perhaps you can look at implementing your navigation like how it is done in the Multipage application here: https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/MultiPageApp/blob/release71/apps/MultiPageApp/common/js/main.js

The sample project is meant to run in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1, but the JavaScript is the same also in Worklight 6.2.